# Recover session after Network Error in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I'm a beginner user of **AWS** and I'm using an **EC2 instance** for MCMC sampling which requires some hours of time. Unfortunately I had a **network problem** in the middle of the sampling and got the message:

```
Network error: Software caused connection abort
```

So that I had to reboot the instance losing all of my work (but not my data).

**Is there a way to set up the instance to avoid this issue?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: if you have the problem once only - well, just bad luck, one out of 100....0. If you see it more than once - something's definitely wrong and requires investigation. ec2 usually are quite reliable, and aws network too.

Comment: Yep, the problem is that today I'm forced to use an unstable connection so it's definitely on my own, but still I'd like to know whether it is possible to let computations go ahead while I'm not connected

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure what MCMC sampling  mean but will try to guess.

The only way not to lost information in such cases is to store it at reliable solution, e.g. S3.

If you meant long calculations then you need to parallel them or at least subdivide to smaller chunks then store the queue, its status and the intermediate results at the reliable storage. Merhaps the code have to be modified. If your calculations can be parallelized then you may want to check SQS and spot instances, sometimes you can save a lot of money.

If my guess is incorrect then pls clarify.

Answer (score 0):

instead of restarting, rebooting the instance will fix this issue most of the time. Instance reboot persist any data on its instance store volumes.